# SQL Server 2012 to 2008 connection

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2012.

I am trying to connect connect to a SQL Server 2008 instance using SQL Server Management Studio 2012, but when I try to connect I get error

> *Cannot connect to PC221327\SQLSERVER.*
>
> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)*

Comment: You have not said what the problem is! You can just connect to a 2008 instance using SSMS 2012. Please elaborate

Comment: Ok, so you get this error for several reasons. The most common is that the SQL Server Service has stopped. this is the first thing to check. I have also been seeing it lately due to firewall issues, and also when wrong port is specified. Is the browser service running?

Comment: Make sure to turn on SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) Service from services.msc

Answer (score 2):

Try to check 2 things:

1. Is the server started? Go to services.msc to see if the server is running
2. Is the server listening on named pipes? Go to the SQL configuration manager from the start menu and check network configuration and then protocols

The error has nothing to do with the version of SQL Server.